# Gerar um array a partir de uma query no mongoDB (Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express.js, mongoose

Bom dia! Preciso dos dados de uma coleção do mongo no front end.

Estou usando o Mongoose como ODM, e fiquei meio perdido na hora de enviar os dados para o front end.

Na query ele me retorna os documentos da coleção, e aí eu preciso deles em JSON (eu acredito) pra usar eles no front end pra gerar um gráfico.

Essa é a rota que eu estou usando

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){

    atendimentos.find({}, async function(err, atendimentos) {
         if(!err){
              console.log(atendimentos);
         }
    })

    res.render('home', {user: req.user, atendimentos: atendimentos});
})
```

Vi que dava pra usar o lean(), mas ele retorna objetos puros do javascript pelo que eu entendi. Eu poderia usar ele e usar um JSON.stringify eu imagino, mas aí na rota não posso usar dois res, se não a aplicação crasha.

Gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer para ter esses dados no front end, se alguém puder me dar uma luz, agradeço muito!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para passar os dados e receber no front.

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    atendimento.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if(!err){
            res.render('home', { result })
        }else{
            console.log(err)
        }            
})
```

E uso ejs como engine de view ai para ter acesso aos dados é bem simples apenas
usando essa sintaxe `<% = atendimento.name %>` ou `<%= user %>`

> Async/await

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, async (req, res) =>{
    const result = await atendimento.find({})
    res.render('home', { result })           
})
```

Comment: Eu preciso dos dados do atendimento no front, o modelo dele no mongo tem 13 campos se eu não me engano, mas eu só preciso de 4 (não sei se isso é relevante, mas eu sei filtrar isso, sem problemas). Acho que desse jeito que tu falou passando const data pode funcionar. Vou testar aqui, preciso dos dados para renderizar um gráfico. Obrigado pela ajuda, vou testar aqui e retorno!

Comment: oks, qualquer coisa só falar.

Comment: Tentei algo assim:  const data = {atendimentos} porque o user já tenho e funciona direitinho, aí passei os dados assim: res.render('home', {user: req.user, chartData: data}, mas aí no gráfico deu que chartData é undefined.

Comment: Mas ai é mesmo coisa que você fez antes, diferença que adicionou mais uma camada nos dados, acho que fica pior assim. Poderia me dar mais informações, de que forma você esta manipulando os dados no front?

Comment: Eu tenho essa view home aí, aí lá eu tenho um script que tem a parte do ChartJS que eu estou querendo usar pra renderizar o gráfico a partir do banco. Lá tem um campo data que é aonde vão os dados, aí tentei passar esse chartData pra lá e não rolou. To meio perdido.

Comment: Então, você saberia me dizer se ta usando alguma engine para a view?

Comment: ExpressJS, .ejs é minha view engine

Comment: Ótimo, o script ta importado na page certo? Se ele estiver charData é sua variavel la, da um `<%=JSON.stringify(chartData)%>` em qualquer lugar da pagina só para ver se os dados estão dentro. Usando esse render seu aqui `res.render('home', {user: req.user, chartData: data}`

Comment: Se for o script do chart, sim. Vou ver aqui, vamos testar. Qualquer coisa vamos para o chat porque aqui  está ficando longo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81008/discussion-between-danibrum-and-ams).